# Best approach to open and parse a file from an FTP (Rails, Sidekiq, SFTP)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sftp, sidekiq

We have a shared FTP with our business partner. The partner sends there text files containing information about orders.

On our side, we run every hour (CRON) a rake task that will connect to the FTP (we're using [SFTP](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp)), then in a loop we list all the files, open one after another one, extract the needed information from there and save it to our database. Then, we delete the file from the FTP.

For an average file, this operation lasts about 20s. If I imagine that we would need to process 20 files, that's almost 7 minutes and my worry is the app would crash.

Here's a pseudo-code we use:

```
namespace :check_ftp do  desc "Check every 30 minutes"
  task :fetch_orders => [:environment] do
    check_dir = '/dir'
    Net::SFTP.start(host, username, password: pass) do |sftp|
      sftp.dir.entries(check_dir).each do |remote_file|
        file_data = sftp.download!(file_path) # loading the file to the buffer
        ... here goes all the parsing ...
        ... here save to the DB ...
        ... log information about this action ...
        ... delete the file from FTP ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What's the best approach to process all the files from the FTP with minimal crashes (ideally none) if the rake task would run ~20mins?

I was thinking that I would run the whole `Net::SFTP.start(...` block with Sidekiq. Then, I was also thinking that I would only run these actions

```
... here goes all the parsing ...
... here save to the DB ...
... log information about this action ...
... delete the file from FTP ...
```

in a Sidekiq job (not the whole `Net::SFTP.start...` block).

What is the best approach here to solve this situation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would say initially, that first you have to say which one of these parts exactly is a time-consuming:
- ... here goes all the parsing ...
- ... here save to the DB ...
- ... log information about this action ...
- ... delete the file from FTP ...

Because wrapping things in sidekiq worker, is just kinda pain-killer, but still the actual problem you have will remain there.

Answer (score 1):

I generally try to break large background jobs down into their atomic parts, which are ultimately spun off from the primary recurring job.

In your case, that would look like this: Move your rake task into a Sidekiq job, and schedule it with something like [sidekiq-cron](https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron).  That job would be responsible for iterating over the files on the FTP server, downloading them, and then enqueuing a job to parse that file (you'd pass the job the path to the file).  In that job, you'd parse the file, save whatever needs to be saved, and ultimately delete the file.

That architecture takes advantage of your various Sidekiq workers, allowing them to concurrently parse files.  Also, if parsing one file fails, it doesn't prevent the rest of the files from being parsed.  You can rely on Sidekiq's built in retry logic to retry parsing that file until it succeeds (due to external factors or a bug fix).  You also end up with quicker jobs, each one focused on a very specific task ("Find all of the files that need parsing", "Parse this specific file").